# Random positioning of pawns on chessboard

Tags: python, random, distribution

I want to (pseudo) randomly position a number points on a grid. Think of it as 10 x 10 chessboard with 100 squares) And think of these points as pawns on the chessboard, that occupy one square each. What I want is for the pawns to be "evenly" distributed over the board. The middle-square method is fine for generating the random numbers.

```
00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  ...
```

My problem that is that if I store the grid squares as list, and draw them from top left to bottom right, then square 9 is not next to 10, as you would expect. 10, is next to 0 & 20. What's the best way around this?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by pseudo random and "evenly" in this case. Unless you make it very clear what rulesand conditions/constraints you have, it will be very difficult to give any answer. Examples on valid and invalid placements would be nice.

Comment: With all power of our imagination we can not reproduce your code. So provide it. And the output as well.

Comment: What I mean my "even" is that there aren't large areas of the board that are heavily over-populated or under-populated; hence pseudo random. There's code to show at this point as I'm stuck as how to go forward

Comment: split it in to 4 smaller 5x5 grids and populate those randomly?

Comment: @The Cat. That might just work. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I can think of no reasonable implementation that would put 9 next to 0 & 20. Could you please show us your implementation that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Element numbering in lists starts with zero, not with 1. So your first square has number 0 (you do see it, right?) and the 10th square has number 9. That is why the 1st square in the 2nd row has number 10 and not 11. It is because 0 + 10 = 10. If you want to print the numbers starting from 1 you can do it adding 1 to a square number in `print`:

```
print (square[number] + 1)
```

As I do not see your code I cannot provide a better code example which would perfectly pass to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you store the final squares as a list, that doesn't mean you have to generate random numbers in a linear range. If you know you have, say, a 100x100 grid, then choose points by choosing X and Y coordinates separately, and then fill in square number 100 * X + Y.

If you want the points distributed randomly, then just make sure you choose both X and Y from a uniform random distribution 0..99. If you want the points distributed evenly, use something like a Halton sequence.